# Prestashop: Displaying image from theme/theme_name/assets/img folder not working

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have an image in my theme in a .tpl file defined like this:

```
<img class="logo" src="/public/img/Logo.svg">
```

However the image is not found even though it is in this directory:

> /themes/theme_name/assets/img/Logo.svg

The result in the console is thus

> GET http://localhost/public/img/Logo.svg 404 (Not Found)

Even though my url to the shop is this:

> http://localhost/prestashop/en/

How do I get prestashop 1.7 to display this image or know where exactly to look for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TPL try with : `<img class="logo" src="{$urls.img_url}Logo.svg">`

Regards